# To get just one aggregated value from the reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, weka

I am trying to print a confusion matrix of J48 classifier using Weka. And the output I am getting is number of matrices from each mapper. The number of mappers running is set to two.

This class is a reducer for the output from the weka classifiers It is given bunch of cross-validated data chunks from the mappers and its job is to aggregate the data into one solution.

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<AggregateableEvaluation> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {      
        int sum = 0;                    
        // loop through each of the values and "aggregate"
        // which basically means to consolidate the values
        for (AggregateableEvaluation val : values) {
            System.out.println("IN THE REDUCER!");

            // The first time through, give aggEval a value
            if (sum == 0) {
                try {
                    aggEval = val;
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                // combine the values
                aggEval.aggregate(val);
            }

            try {
                // This is what is taken from the mapper to be aggregated
                //System.out.println("This is the map result");
                //System.out.println(aggEval.toMatrixString());
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                       

            sum += 1;
        }           
        try {
            System.out.println("This is reduce matrix");
            System.out.println(aggEval.toMatrixString());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Dont get it. what is the question?

Comment: @Zelldon I am trying to print a confusion matrix ie weka output but i am getting many matrices ... i am not sure but its like reducer is being executed many number of times.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about WEKA, but with "normal" mapreduce, your reduce function should be of the form: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Reducer.html

```
 public class IntSumReducer<Key> extends Reducer<Key,IntWritable,
                                                 Key,IntWritable> {
   private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

   public void reduce(Key key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                      Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     int sum = 0;
     for (IntWritable val : values) {
       sum += val.get();
     }
     result.set(sum);
     context.write(key, result);
   }
 }
```

So basically, **the Reducer method is called once for *each* of your keys**.  You'll get all of the values that map to that particular key, which you should aggreagate together, and then when you're done do a `context.write(key, aggEval)` to emit the results from your reduce method

Comment: I tried what you told, but the problem is, I need to use AggregateableEvaluation instead of IntWritable so context.write is not allowing (key,aggEval). it expects key and IntWritable type

Comment: The type in the Iterable<> doesn't have to match the type emit'd in the context.  So either you have to aggregate your AggregateableEvaluation's into an IntWritable, or you need to change the type of what the reduce phase emits.  You'll notice that the Reducer is of the form <K1,V1, K2, V2>. V2 is the type that you are emitting.

Comment: The thing is i need to output the matrix which is of type evaluation class toMatrixString produces a confusion matrix.. so can i cant aggregate into IntWritable right? and also emitting it in any other type wont give matrix right ?

Comment: Is this your code here: https://github.com/thodde/weka-hadoop/blob/master/src/WekDoop.java#L354

Comment: Its not mine, i am trying to implement the same.

Comment: If all you're trying to output is a sting, change the `V2` to a `Text` class and you can do a `context.write(key, new Text(aggEval.toMatrixString())`

Comment: I tried doing that.. I'm getting output in hdfs output and entire dataset info is getting displayed.. Other than that AggrrgatableEvaluation class name is getting displayed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75950/discussion-between-amogh-and-furiousgeorge).